# Loop starting from 0 or 1? Which one and why?

Tags: c++, performance, embedded

Most of the for loops I have read/written start from 0 and to be fair most of the code I have read are used for embedded systems and they were in C/C++. In embedded systems the readability is not as important as code efficiency in some cases. Therefore, I am not sure which of the following cases would be a better choice:

**version 1**

```
for(i = 0; i < allowedNumberOfIteration; i++)
{
//something that may take from 1 iteration to allowedNumberOfIteration before it happens
  if(somethingHappened)
  {
     if(i + 1 > maxIteration)
     {
       maxIteration = i + 1;
     }
  }
}
```

**Version 2**

```
for(i = 1; i <= allowedNumberOfIteration; i++)
{
//something that may take from 1 iteration to allowedNumberOfIteration before it happens
  if(somethingHappened)
  {
     if(i > maxIteration)
     {
       maxIteration = i;
     }
  }
}
```

**Why first version is better in my opinion:**

1.Most loops starts with 0. So, maybe experienced programmers find it to be better if it starts from 0.

**Why second version is better in my opinion:**

1. To be fair if there was an array in the function starting from 0
   would be great because the index of arrays start from zero. But in
   this part of the code no arrays are used.
2. Beside the second version looks simpler because you do not have to think about the '+1'.

**Things I do not know**

1) Is there any performance difference?

2) Which version is better?

3) Are there any other aspect that should be considered in deciding the starting point?

4) Am I worrying too much?

Comment: IMHO starting from `0` is more natural as most (maybe all) ranges in the standard are expressed as `[begin, end)` where your range is `(begin, end]`.

Comment: Yes, you're worrying too much. A good compiler will generate whatever form of loop is fastest and adjust behind the scenes, invisibly.

Comment: The one thing I would worry about in this situation is keeping starting indices consistend throughout your codebase (where applicable).

Comment: Just write code in a way which you and somebody else can undestand. Optimise when necessery.

Comment: NathanOliver: Thank you, I guess I will do the same
Mark Ransom: That is a part of the question and in embedded systems the compilers may not be very efficient, but as far as I can tell these two should be identical.
Pandatyr: Thank you, but in some cases it is not possible.
wowofbod: yeah good point. But some embedded compiler are not very smart. For this case I think both versions are easy to understand and I could judge on my own (working on this project alone).

Comment: "In embedded systems the readability is not as important as code efficiency" - You are very wrong. Especially in embedded systesm with >10 years of maintenance readability is vital. Concentrate on writing clear and understandable code first. Don't do premature optionisations (which does not imply writing overly complex code). Optimise **hotspots** after profiling. If you have a good architecture, this will result in the best code from both views.

Comment: At the risk of piling on, Just write clean code.  The compiler is smarter than you -- don't worry about making the compiler's life easier.  The person that maintains your code (possibly your future self) is not as smart as you -- worry about making the maintainer's life easier.  Start the loop at whatever value makes sense for the abstraction you're creating.  And consider naming the loop variable in terms of the abstraction (`i` doesn't help much).

Comment: It probably makes more sense to make `maxIteration` zero-indexed too. So that you use the 0-based loop and compare `if(i == maxIteration)`.

Comment: @Olaf With all respect, I said "in some cases". Honestly after checking your account I am sure you know more than me, but I have seen enough code for 8-bit processors to make a judgment on how things are done. I totally understand your point. But it is unfair to consider the majority of the code written for 8-bit processors as readable. Whether we like it or not, it has already been done. Now regarding my question, I think most people did not read it all. In my reasoning on which may be a better way I did not consider performance at all but readability.

Comment: @kkrambo actually the whole question is asking which one is more readable but I do not understand why everyone is so focused about the small section which ask about the performance differences.

Comment: @Lundin I actually made the mistake myself when I was looking at the code again. So how does the reader knows if a variable starts from 0 or in other word 0 means a 1? Is there a standard way to show that?

Comment: @Ali: "But it is unfair to consider the majority of the code written for 8-bit processors as readable" - Non sequitur! Even if this was true, it does not mean one cannot implement the same functionality with clean(er) and maintainable code. I very well know a lot of "old-school" programmers tend to do premature optimisations, distrusting the compiler for historical reasons. I've seen more than one of them being baffled seeing the machine code a modern compiler generates from readable C source code. "8 bit CPU" is no excuse for writing bad overall code since years (it is common, though).

Comment: @Olaf I could not say it any better. Honestly I myself used to use a C compiler (CV) for AVRs and the compiler was very tricky and I had to do everything myself. Now, I am using Arduino IDE (C++) and I have tried so many of the tricks necessary in CV but the compiler is very smart and the "inefficient" looking code runs just as good. But unfortunately when you check the Arduino libraries, you see many of old tricks are still used (ex. Still everything is #define). Anyways my main question was about readability. I think they are both equally readable, so I gave up worrying. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ali, if you want to improve readability then use a more descriptive name for the loop counter variable.  `i` doesn't really provide any insight.  When looping through an array I typically name the variable `index` because I believe that name suggests the loop starts at 0 and indexes an array.  But for other loops something like `widget_count` or `num_widgets` might provide some clarity.

Comment: @Ali: Arduino is not exactly C++; don't stomp into that minefield. I had very smart 8 bit compilers ca. 18 years ago which in fact convinced me moving from assembly to C. And that was a very compiler-unfriendly CPU. So no excuses. If you read my former comments, you should notice the major problem often is the architecture, not the implementations. For instance avoiding bloatware vendor-libraries like the STlib is a good approach.

Comment: @kkrambo: Thank you, I think this is a good suggestion but then I was thinking to follow this
http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html#Conditionals
so I used i. Let me know your thoughts on the link.

Comment: @Olaf I am working on an opensource project. To my knowledge, projects with Arduino IDE become more successful because more people use it. I think the other alternative is Atmel Studio which I have never used but I am sure more people prefer Arduino IDE even though the IDE is garbage. BTW can you explain "Arduino is not exactly C++", I am not sure what you mean by that. So far I noticed only lists and vectors were not supported (I'm no pro).
"architecture, not the implementations." Thank you for pointing it out your_exposure > my_exposure.*100. :) thanks, I never looked at it that way.

Comment: "projects with Arduino IDE become more successful because more people use it" - few to no professional projects use arduino. Can you pad your assumption with any proof? "I think the other alternative" - There are way more than two alternatives. And none is a compiler. You are aware there are much more MCU families and CPU architectures than AVR and ARM Cortex-M, are you? For the rest: get a good C++ book and learn the language; this has been explained so often here and elsewhere already. One aspect is you cannot use all features (or, if you would, the code would be unacceptably bloated&slow).

Comment: @Olaf If you want your project to be easily accessible and modified by all its user who may not be very good in programming, which platform would you use (MCU and compiler)? This is the criteria that I am concerned with. If we consider Spartkfun to be one of the distributors for my target niche, you only see name of 3 platforms (Arduino(64,900,000), Raspberry Pi(37,500,000), Intel® Edison(482,000)) as a main category. (The numbers show the google search result for each platform.)
Moreover let me know what MCU you love the most, please.
For C++ noted, thank you.

Comment: You picked the wrong criterions. First, the platform should be choosen appropriately to your problem. Then the price, Existing experience is another factor, but not the major. Finally: programmers should have sufficient experience in embedded programming; this is a very different field than writing simple PC-level software! As a sidenote: the MCU market is far beyond the billion units per year (the classic 8051 family alone is). google search hits don't prove anything. And no, I will not set a recommendation to a MCU, just because that depends on the problem.

Comment: @Olaf I want to make an open source controller for robotics application. So, wide range of users should be able to use it/modify it. In fact, some of the target users are in high school. This is why I think Arduino would be the best choice, let me know if you think otherwise.
But I do understand the criteria you mentioned but I think for this project a different point of view is required.
I agree that embedded programming is different from software for PC. But Arduino has proven that people with ~0 background can get stuff done. (not perfect but it works and definitely better than nothing)

Comment: @Ali: Professional embedded is very different from the hobbyist market - luckily. Let's settle it with that.

Comment: @olaf ok, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry to disturb you again.
Could you please introduce a good open source library for a Graphical LCD or something complicated with low level access for preferably AVRs (any other 8-bit MCU would be great too), so that I can adapt as many as good practices and structures possible?
Thank you and sorry for taking your time again.

Comment: @Ali: This is not a recommendation site. And you need to pick a library suitable for your problem. As a sidenote: 8 bit MCUs are not well suited for such things, 16 bit are not much better. Better get an ARM-based MCU. Writing a graphics lib is not that complicated at all. I wrote several in assembly language (some on 8 bitters, but these were different times). One important aspect of embedded design is selecting appropriate tools and system components.

Comment: @Olaf I am writing mine and it is almost finished(70%). I have not shared it online because some higher level features are not developed yet. As I said the target user would appreciate AVRs a lot more.
I would be happy if you could show me a sample library for what you would consider professional embedded system library (open source) for a 8-bit MCU. Anyways, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) No

2) Neither

3) Arrays in C and C++ are zero-based.

4) Yes.

Comment: I wish you could answer 2 differently. :) That leaves me on the same spot as when I started. :) I would be happy to see know what you would do personally.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays of all forms in C++ are *zero-based*. I.e. their index start at zero and goes up to the size of the array *minus one*. For example an array of five elements will have the indexes `0` to `4` (inclusive).

*That* is why most loops in C++ are starting at zero.

---

As for your specific list of questions, for *1* there *might* be a performance difference. If you start a loop at `1` then you might need to subtract `1` in each iterator if you use the value as an array index. Or if you increase the size of the arrays then you use more memory.

For *2* it really depends on what you're iterating over. Is it over array indexes, then the loop starting at zero is clearly better. But you might need to start a loop at *any* value, it really depends on what you're doing and the problem you're trying to solve.

For *3*, what you need to consider is what you're *using* the loop for.

And *4*, maybe a little. ;)

Comment: I think I am explaining a specific case in my question so I think question can be answered specifically. I would be happy to know which one you would pick considering all the stuff I wrote regarding this specific case.

Comment: @Ali In the specific case of the code shown in the question, I wouldn't pick *either*. Because no loop is needed to calculate `maxIteration`.

Comment: As I said this is for embedded system so I need to wait for hardware to respond. I have put a threshold for waiting by setting an allowedNumberOfIteration. However in most cases the hardware respond earlier. So, I want to track the maximum number of iteration required after running the system for hours and check if the chip variation effects this number. I am sorry if my explanation did not make it clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This argument comes from a small, 3-page note by the famous computer scientist Dijkstra (the one from Dijkstra's algorithm). In it, he lays out the reasons we might index starting at zero, and the story begins with trying to iterate over a sequence of natural numbers (meaning a sequence on the number line 0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

There are 4 possibilities to index 2, 3, ..., 12.

a.) `2 <= i < 13`

b.) `1 < i <= 12`

c.) `2 <= i <= 12`

d.) `1 < i < 13`

He mentions that a.) and b.) have the advantage that the difference of the two bounds equals the number of elements in the sequence. He also mentions if two sequences are adjacent, the upper bound of one equals the lower bound of the other. He says this doesn't help decide between a.) or b.) so he will start afresh.

He immediately removes b.) and d.) from the list since, if we were to start a natural sequence with zero, they would have bounds outside the natural numbers (-1), which is "ugly". He completes the observation by saying we prefer `<=` for the lower bound -- leaving us with a.) and c.).

For an empty set, he notes that in b.) and c.) will have -1 for its upper bound, which is also "ugly".

All three of these observations leads to the convention to represent a sequence of natural numbers with a.), and that indeed is how most people write a `for` that goes over an array: `for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)`. We include the lower bound (`i <= 0`), and we exclude the upper bound (`i < size`).

If you were to use something like `for(int i = 0; i <= iterations - 1; ++i)` to do `i` iterations, you can see the ugliness he refers to in the case of the empty set. `iterations - 1` would be `-1` for zero iterations.

So by convention, we use a.) and due to indexing arrays at zero, we start a huge number for `for` loops with `i = 0`. Then, we reason parsimony - might as well do different things the exact same way if there is no other reason to do one or the other a different way.

Now, if we were to use a.) with 1-based indexing into an array instead of 0-based indexing, we would get `for(int i = 1; i < size + 1; ++i)`. The `+ 1` is "ugly", so we prefer to start our range with `i = 0`.

In conclusion, you should do a `for` `iterations` times with `for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)`. Something like `for(int i = 1; i <= iterations; ++i)` is fairly understandable and works, but is there any good reason to add a different way to loop `iterations` times? Just use the same pattern as when indexing an array. In other words, use `0 <= i < size`. Worse, the loop based on `1 <= i <= iterations` doesn't have all the reasons Dijkstra came up with to support using `0 <= i < iterations` as a convention.

You're not worrying too much. In fact, Dijkstra himself wondered the exact same question as has pretty much any serious programmer. Tuning your style like a craftsman who loves their trade is the ground a great programmer stands on. Pursuing parsimony and writing code the way others tend to write code (including yourself - the looping of an array!) are both sane, great things to pursue.

Due to this convention, when I see `for(i = 1`, I notice a departure from a convention. I am then more cautious around that code, thinking the logic within the `for` might depend on starting at `1` instead of `0`. This is slight, but there's no reason to add that possibility when a convention is so widely used. If you happen to have a large `for` body, this complaint becomes less slight.

To understand why starting at one makes no sense, consider taking the argument to its natural conclusion - the argument of "but it makes sense to me!": You can start `i` at anything! If we free ourselves from convention, why not loop `for(int i = 5; i <= iterations + 4; ++i)`? Or `for(int i = -5; i > -iterations - 5; --i)`? Just do it the way a majority of programmers do in the majority of cases, and save being different for when there's a good reason - the difference signals to the programmer reading your code that the body of the `for` contains something unusual. With the standard way, we know the `for` is either indexing/ordering/doing arithmetic with a sequence starting at 0 or executing some logic `iterations` times in a row.

Note how prevalent this convention is too. In C++, every standard container iterates between `[start, end)`, which corresponds to a.) above. There, they do it so that the end condition can be `iter != end`, but the fact that we already do the logic one way and that that one way has no immediate drawbacks flows naturally into the argument of "Why do it two different ways when we already do it this way in this context?" In his little paper, Dijkstra also notes a language called Mesa that can do a.), b.), c.), or d.) with particular syntax. He claims that there, a.) has won out in practice, and the others are associated with the cause of bugs. He then laments how FORTRAN indexes at 1 and how PASCAL took on c.) by convention.